# Delete User From onlineUsers Table On Logout

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Logout.php

```
<?php
require('includes/database.php');
require('includes/initialize.php');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$onlineUsers = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM `onlineUsers` WHERE `username`='$username'");
$onlineUsers -> execute();
sleep(1);
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['ID']);
session_destroy();
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

onlineUsers Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `onlineUsers` (
`username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`isStaff` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If you login successfully it adds you to the table fine, and I would like when you logout for it to remove you from the table. Logging out works fine EXCEPT for the part I need help with (removing user from onlineUsers)

Comment: What about placeing `session_start();` above all lines!?

Comment: @RezaSaberi Boy do I feel stupid right now :| thank you my friend.

Comment: it depends on your way of looking at my comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you started your session after some code. you should start your session at the starting of your php code like this

```
<?php
   session_start();
```

Answer (score 2):

We should start the session properly before accessing it,For example.
Your code should be like this.

```
If ( !isset($_SESSION))
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about how to query the DB to delete a row containing an online user? What you likely want to do is something like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE username=something;
```

In this case you'll pass the username of the user you want to remove from the DB.